# java play 2.3 on openshift never updates

Tags: java, deployment, playframework, openshift

i have created a java play 2.3 (activator) application and pushed my code to an openshift server by following those steps :

https://github.com/JamesSullivan/play2-openshift-quickstart

however my application has never updated and i tried to restart it many times and re push my code again and again with no use as if i have pushed nothing although i have tried to clone my application repository and i saw that the repository has the latest commits , so what would i be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also followed the same guide and I successfully deployed a play!2.4 on openshift just right now (with a bit of modifications done for adding java 8). what you are facing sounds like you are pushing not into a right git remote.

what I would suggest you is to either using [rhc](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-client-tools.html) or plant ssh to connect to your openshift server and then, check there the git logs. 
from that point you could understand whether your settings of git remote are wrong or not.

if they are wrong, use

> git remote add origin ssh://your_uuid@play2demo-yourdomain.rhcloud.com/~/git/play2demo.git/

as it's shown in the guide to add your openshift remote repository and then push to it

if they are correct, I would suggest you to goto

```
$ cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/.openshift/action_hooks/
$ chmod +x start
$ ./start
```

that would start the application. 
btw, if the start hook is not executable you can change it using

```
$ git update-index --add --chmod=+x .openshift/action_hooks/start
$ git commit -m 'change mode'
$ git push origin
```